# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at home.<init>(home.java:43) at home.main(home.java:425)

Tags: java

this is causing a problem as well as i am getting connectivity issue using jdbc and odbc bridge for my entire project
i have to link my vfp .dbf files to java but jdk 8.0 doesnt support jdbc-odbc bridge

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class home extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  /**
   *
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  JMenuBar menuBar;
  JMenu st, bill, rep, oth;
  JOptionPane jp = new JOptionPane();
  JMenuItem adi, ade, edi, ede, gbil, cbil, bpay, days, bals, dds, nils, empa, cp, per, emae;
  Container c;
  int in = 0, i = 0, t = 0;
  int pr[] = new int[15];
  String pe = null;
  public home() {
    super("Billing Projects                                         ::Ram Kishan Jiva Ram::");
    c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(new Color(255, 179, 179));
    c.setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0, 0, 850, 590);




    if (pe.equals("other")) {


      ImageIcon coll = new ImageIcon("ifill.JPG");
      JLabel LogoColl = new JLabel(coll);
      LogoColl.setBounds(0, 25, 850, 550);
      c.add(LogoColl);
      menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      st = new JMenu("Stock");
      st.setBackground(Color.white);
      st.setMnemonic('S');
      bill = new JMenu("Bill");
      bill.setBackground(Color.white);
      bill.setMnemonic('B');
      rep = new JMenu("Reports");
      rep.setMnemonic('R');
      rep.setBackground(Color.white);
      oth = new JMenu("Other");
      oth.setMnemonic('O');
      oth.setBackground(Color.white);
      if (pr[0] == 1) {
        adi = new JMenuItem("Add Item");
        adi.setBackground(Color.white);
        adi.setMnemonic('A');
        adi.addActionListener(this);
        st.add(adi);
      }
      if (pr[1] == 1) {
        edi = new JMenuItem("Edit Item");
        edi.setBackground(Color.white);
        edi.setMnemonic('E');
        edi.addActionListener(this);
        st.add(edi);
      }
      if (pr[2] == 1) {
        ade = new JMenuItem("Add Empolyee");
        ade.setBackground(Color.white);
        ade.setMnemonic('d');
        ade.addActionListener(this);
        st.add(ade);
      }
      if (pr[3] == 1) {
        ede = new JMenuItem("Edit Empolyee");
        ede.setBackground(Color.white);
        ede.setMnemonic('i');
        ede.addActionListener(this);
        st.add(ede);
      }
      if (pr[4] == 1) {
        gbil = new JMenuItem("Generate Bill");
        gbil.setBackground(Color.white);
        gbil.setMnemonic('G');
        gbil.addActionListener(this);
        bill.add(gbil);
      }
      if (pr[5] == 1) {
        cbil = new JMenuItem("Cancel Bill");
        cbil.setBackground(Color.white);
        cbil.setMnemonic('C');
        cbil.addActionListener(this);
        bill.add(cbil);
      }
      if (pr[6] == 1) {
        bpay = new JMenuItem("Bill Payment");
        bpay.setBackground(Color.white);
        bpay.setMnemonic('B');
        bpay.addActionListener(this);
        bill.add(bpay);
      }
      if (pr[7] == 1) {
        days = new JMenuItem("Day Wise Sale");
        days.setBackground(Color.white);
        days.setMnemonic('D');
        days.addActionListener(this);
        rep.add(days);
      }
      if (pr[8] == 1) {
        bals = new JMenuItem("Balence Stock");
        bals.setBackground(Color.white);
        bals.setMnemonic('B');
        bals.addActionListener(this);
        rep.add(bals);
      }
      if (pr[9] == 1) {
        dds = new JMenuItem("Day To Day Sale");
        dds.setBackground(Color.white);
        dds.setMnemonic('T');
        dds.addActionListener(this);
        rep.add(dds);
      }
      if (pr[10] == 1) {
        nils = new JMenuItem("Nil Stock");
        nils.setBackground(Color.white);
        nils.setMnemonic('N');
        nils.addActionListener(this);
        rep.add(nils);
      }
      if (pr[11] == 1) {
        empa = new JMenuItem("Employee Attendence");
        empa.setBackground(Color.white);
        empa.setMnemonic('E');
        empa.addActionListener(this);
        rep.add(empa);
      }
      if (pr[12] == 1) {
        emae = new JMenuItem("Employee Attendence Entry");
        emae.setBackground(Color.white);
        emae.setMnemonic('E');
        emae.addActionListener(this);
        oth.add(emae);
      }
      setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      menuBar.add(st);
      menuBar.add(bill);
      menuBar.add(rep);
      menuBar.add(oth);

      c.add(menuBar);

    } else
    if (pe.equals("admin")) {


      ImageIcon coll = new ImageIcon("ifill.JPG");
      JLabel LogoColl = new JLabel(coll);
      LogoColl.setBounds(0, 25, 850, 550);
      c.add(LogoColl);
      menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      st = new JMenu("Stock");
      st.setBackground(Color.white);
      st.setMnemonic('S');
      bill = new JMenu("Bill");
      bill.setBackground(Color.white);
      bill.setMnemonic('B');
      rep = new JMenu("Reports");
      rep.setMnemonic('R');
      rep.setBackground(Color.white);
      oth = new JMenu("Other");
      oth.setMnemonic('O');
      oth.setBackground(Color.white);
      adi = new JMenuItem("Add Item");
      adi.setBackground(Color.white);
      adi.setMnemonic('A');
      adi.addActionListener(this);
      st.add(adi);
      edi = new JMenuItem("Edit Item");
      edi.setBackground(Color.white);
      edi.setMnemonic('E');
      edi.addActionListener(this);
      st.add(edi);
      ade = new JMenuItem("Add Empolyee");
      ade.setBackground(Color.white);
      ade.setMnemonic('d');
      ade.addActionListener(this);
      st.add(ade);
      ede = new JMenuItem("Edit Empolyee");
      ede.setBackground(Color.white);
      ede.setMnemonic('i');
      ede.addActionListener(this);
      st.add(ede);
      gbil = new JMenuItem("Generate Bill");
      gbil.setBackground(Color.white);
      gbil.setMnemonic('G');
      gbil.addActionListener(this);
      bill.add(gbil);
      cbil = new JMenuItem("Cancel Bill");
      cbil.setBackground(Color.white);
      cbil.setMnemonic('C');
      cbil.addActionListener(this);
      bill.add(cbil);
      bpay = new JMenuItem("Bill Payment");
      bpay.setBackground(Color.white);
      bpay.setMnemonic('B');
      bpay.addActionListener(this);
      bill.add(bpay);
      days = new JMenuItem("Day Wise Sale");
      days.setBackground(Color.white);
      days.setMnemonic('D');
      days.addActionListener(this);
      rep.add(days);
      bals = new JMenuItem("Balence Stock");
      bals.setBackground(Color.white);
      bals.setMnemonic('B');
      bals.addActionListener(this);
      rep.add(bals);
      dds = new JMenuItem("Day To Day Sale");
      dds.setBackground(Color.white);
      dds.setMnemonic('T');
      dds.addActionListener(this);
      rep.add(dds);
      nils = new JMenuItem("Nil Stock");
      nils.setBackground(Color.white);
      nils.setMnemonic('N');
      nils.addActionListener(this);
      rep.add(nils);
      empa = new JMenuItem("Employee Attendence");
      empa.setBackground(Color.white);
      empa.setMnemonic('E');
      empa.addActionListener(this);
      rep.add(empa);
      emae = new JMenuItem("Employee Attendence Entry");
      emae.setBackground(Color.white);
      emae.setMnemonic('E');
      emae.addActionListener(this);
      oth.add(emae);
      cp = new JMenuItem("Change Password");
      cp.setBackground(Color.white);
      cp.setMnemonic('C');
      cp.addActionListener(this);
      per = new JMenuItem("Permissions");
      per.setBackground(Color.white);
      per.setMnemonic('P');
      oth.add(cp);
      oth.add(per);
      setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      menuBar.add(st);
      menuBar.add(bill);
      menuBar.add(rep);
      menuBar.add(oth);
      cp.addActionListener(this);
      per.addActionListener(this);
      c.add(menuBar);


      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(false);
    }
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String str1 = (String) ae.getActionCommand();
    Object source = ae.getSource();



    if (source == adi) {
      this.dispose();
      aitem u1 = new aitem();
      u1.n1();
    }
    if (source == edi) {
      this.dispose();
      eitem u2 = new eitem();
      u2.n2();
    }


    if (source == ade) {
      this.dispose();
      aemp u3 = new aemp();
      u3.n3();
    }
    if (source == ede) {
      this.dispose();
      eemp u4 = new eemp();
      u4.n4();
    }



    if (source == gbil) {
      this.dispose();
      gen u5 = new gen();
      u5.n5();

    }

    if (source == cbil) {
      this.dispose();
      canbill u6 = new canbill();
      u6.n6();
    }

    if (source == bpay) {
      this.dispose();
      paybill u7 = new paybill();
      u7.n7();

    }

    if (source == days) {
      this.dispose();
      daysale u8 = new daysale();
      u8.n8();

    }
    if (source == bals) {
      this.dispose();
      bal u9 = new bal();
      u9.n9();
    }
    if (source == dds) {
      this.dispose();
      day2day u10 = new day2day();
      u10.n10();
    }
    if (source == nils) {
      this.dispose();
      nil u11 = new nil();
      u11.n11();
    }
    if (source == empa) {
      this.dispose();
      emprep u12 = new emprep();
      u12.n12();

    }
    if (source == emae) {
      this.dispose();
      empatt u13 = new empatt();
      u13.n13();
    }


    if (source == cp) {
      this.dispose();
      cpass u19 = new cpass();
      u19.n19();
    }


    if (source == per) {
      this.dispose();
      perm u15 = new perm();
      u15.n15();
    }


    if (str1.equals("Exit")) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
  public void nn(String p, String un, String pa, String id) {

    pe = p;

    if (p.equals("other")) {
      try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sysDSN", "system", "manager");
        Statement stm = c.createStatement();
        t = 0; in = 0;
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from perm where id=" + id);
        while (rs.next()) {
          t = 1;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;
          pr[ in ] = rs.getInt( in +3); in ++;



        }
        if (t == 0) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry, No Such Record exisits", "INFORMATION", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          t = 0;
        }
        c.close();
        stm.close();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, cnf, "EXCEPTION", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Cnf Exception");
      } catch (SQLException sql) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, sql, "EXCEPTION", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }


    }
  }@
  SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    home u = new home();
    u.setResizable(false);
    u.setBounds(0, 0, 850, 590);
    u.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: you have an if condition to load the jdbc driver, did you check if it is passing the condition? It seems your check(pe) has a null value.

Comment: On line 43 you try to call `pe.equals(...)` in the constructor, but `pe` is initialized to null on line 32.